# Excel on return, tab or cursor - advance to next cell keeps failing

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Often when I re-open a spreadsheet I find that:

- the Enter/Return key fails to advance to next row
- the tab key fails to advance to the next cell
- the cursor keys fail to move the next cell in the key's direction.
- left and right cursor keys do sometimes work but do not move to next or previous cell, they inconsistently jump around the worksheet *(e.g starting at J67 -> left cursor -> land on F4 -> right cursor -> land on A1173**4** -> left cursor -> land on F4 -> then left and right jumps backwards and forwards between A1173**3** and F4 (note change in high row cell number))*

When the spreadsheet is in this state when I finish editing a cell and press any of the above keys the just edited cell remains selected.

Invariably after a while of working on the spreadsheet the keys start working as expected and return/tab/cursors do exactly as listed above.

I know that the details of which cell to advance to can be configured in Excel, but this is not a question about that. I have not changed those settings from default and I do not change them during the editing session

This has been happening for years and happens on any spreadsheet I am working on so it doesn't seem to be corruption of a particular spreadsheet.

Neither is it particular to this installation, I had the same problem on other machines, and colleagues have seen the same thing.

I also seem to remember it happening with Excel 2007.

I haven't been able to identify any pattern or particular operation that results in the keys suddenly starting to work as expected again.

(Excel version 2010)

Comment: Is this a protected sheet? Is it shared from a network resource where multiple people may be trying to access it at the same time?

Comment: Not protected and the problem happens with docs on local or shared drives.